# C++ - Smooth speedup and slowing of objects

Tags: c++, algorithm, interpolation

I am dealing with some positions of objects in Cocos2dx but this question can apply to virtually every situation in which a smooth start and stop is necessary.

Here's what I am looking for:

Given a origin position at x = 0 and a final position of x = 8, I want to accelerate slowly and get further the further I am from the start and then have it slow down as it reaches the end. Is there a smoothing algorithm for this?

Comment: The website http://easings.net/ is a good source for various easing functions. What you described would be probably fall under easeInOutQuart or easeInOutExpo. Although the code is in JavaScript, I've found it pretty straightforward to port to C/C++.

Comment: @flashk Thanks. I didn't even know the term.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of algorithms for this.  One idea is to set up a linear interpolation:

```
x(t) = t * x0 + (1.0 - t) * x1;
```

If you feed evenly spaced values of `t` from 0.0 to 1.0, you'll get a smooth, linear animation.

If you want slow start and slow end, you can use `t = sin(theta)/2.0 + 1.0` for `theta` from -pi/2 to pi/2.

Comment: The latter's roughly what I would have grabbed first as a least-thought solution.  Last time I did this I also wanted a fancier path, so wound up with a spline curve.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure a sine function really does a slow start.  But some sort of spline curve would definitely do the trick.

Comment: Cosine would. (X-axis, not Y-axis, projection.)

Comment: This isn't smooth: the acceleration at t=0 is infinite, zero in between, and minus infinite at t=1. You really can't do worse than that.

Answer (score 1):

A second-order smooth path has constant acceleration during the first half, then constant deceleration during the second part.

This means you accelerate from `x=0` to `x=4`. The formula is `x(t)=a*t*t` so your choice of acceleration `a` directly influences the time needed. If you set the deceleration to the same value, you'll arrive after twice the time in `x=8`. The formula for the second part is therefore `x(t) = 16 - a*t*t`. The halfway point in time is `t=sqrt(4/a)`.